# Bootstrap 4 flex does not support xs

Tags: bootstrap-4

I want to update my website ui for xs screen but bootstrap 4 flex does not provide support for xs so what is the proper way to implement flex for extra small screens.

Comment: v4 is still in alpha stage. Did you read the [Migration document](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/) ?

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
     <div class="col-12">
      instead of 
     <div class="col-xs-12">
```

see [here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/) for more detail